# Why am I getting an unrecognized selector error?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mqttDataClient.delegate = self
    mqttDataClient.connect()
    let tableRefresh = UIRefreshControl()
    tableView.refreshControl = tableRefresh
    tableRefresh.addTarget(tableView, action: #selector(updateTable), for: .valueChanged)
    tableRefresh.endRefreshing()
}

@objc func updateTable(){
    print("R")
    mqttDataClient.publish("control", withString: "sendMovieList")

}
```

crashes with the following error:

> -[UITableView updateTable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106008a00

I am using Xcode 10 on macOS 10.14.  I think I have this set up correctly and I am wondering if it's an issue with the new xCode. I mean the selector is right there, right?

Comment: You probably want `addTarget(self, ...)` – You can see from the error that the message is sent to the table view, not to the view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updateTable` is a method of your view controller, not the table view.

Change:

```
tableRefresh.addTarget(tableView, action: #selector(updateTable), for: .valueChanged)
```

to:

```
tableRefresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateTable), for: .valueChanged)
```

The `target` must always be the class that implements the selector.

Comment: reloadData() is called elsewhere in response to the `mqttDataClient.publish` call

Comment: @PeterWiley OK, removed that part.